# Can Ordnance Survey Ireland georeferenced 25" historical maps be downloaded?

Tags: qgis, download

I'm using QGIS3 and want to download to use as a background layer an OSI 25" historic map.  It can be viewed in OSI's map viewer, and is georeferenced with the Irish Transverse Mercator grid.  Can the georeferenced file be downloaded?  If so, how do I go about it?

Comment: please add a link to the OSI map viewer, so we can see how they do it

Comment: http://maps.osi.ie/publicviewer is the viewer, Ian.

Comment: If you want to know what is available online for free, visit https://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Maps/Ireland

Answer (score 2):

According to their FAQ, you can purchase a ["digital planning pack"](https://www.osi.ie/products/professional-mapping/planning-pack/) either online or by emailing digitals@osi.ie. If you have further questions about what materials are included in a digital planning pack, your best course will be to direct them to the same email address.